# PySpark 2.2.0 : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'indices'

Tags: python, pyspark

#### Task

I'm calculating the size on the indices within a `__SparseVector__` using Python API for Spark (PySpark).

#### Script

```
def score_clustering(dataframe):
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = dataframe.drop("documento").columns, outputCol = "variables")
data_transformed = assembler.transform(dataframe)
data_transformed_rdd = data_transformed.select("documento", "variables").orderBy(data_transformed.documento.asc()).rdd
count_variables = data_transformed_rdd.map(lambda row : [row[0], row[1].indices.size]).toDF(["id", "frequency"])
```

#### Issue

When I execute the action `__.count()__` on the `__count_variables__` dataframe an error shows up:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'indices'

The main part to consider is:

> data_transformed_rdd.map(lambda row : [row[0], row[1].indices.size]).toDF(["id", "frequency"])

I believe this chunk has to do with the error, but I cannot understand why the exception is telling about `__numpy.ndarray__` if I'm doing the calculations through mapping that `__lambda expression__` whose taking as argument a `__SparseVector__` (created with the `__assembler__`).

Any suggestions? Does anyone maybe know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first one is in `indices.size` call, `indices` and `size` are two different attributes of [SparseVector class](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py), `size` is the complete vector size and `indices` are the vector indices whose values are non-zero, but `size` is not a `indices` attribute. So, assuming that all your vectors are instances of SparseVector class:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, Vectors.sparse(4, [0, 1], [11.0, 2.0])),
                            (1, Vectors.sparse(4, [], [])),
                            (3, Vectors.sparse(4, [0,1,2], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]))],
                           ["documento", "variables"])

df.show()

+---------+--------------------+
|documento|           variables|
+---------+--------------------+
|        0|(4,[0,1],[11.0,2.0])|
|        1|           (4,[],[])|
|        3|(4,[0,1,2],[2.0,2...|
+---------+--------------------+
```

The solution is `len` function:

```
df = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], len(x[1].indices)))\
               .toDF(["documento", "variables", "frecuencia"])
df.show()  
+---------+--------------------+----------+
|documento|           variables|frecuencia|
+---------+--------------------+----------+
|        0|(4,[0,1],[11.0,2.0])|         2|
|        1|           (4,[],[])|         0|
|        3|(4,[0,1,2],[2.0,2...|         3|
+---------+--------------------+----------+
```

And here comes the second problem: VectorAssembler does not always generate SparseVectors, depending on what is more efficient, SparseVector or DenseVectors can be generated (based on the number of zeros that your original vector has). For example, suppose the next data frame:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, Vectors.sparse(4, [0, 1], [11.0, 2.0])),
                             (1, Vectors.dense([1., 1., 1., 1.])),
                              (3, Vectors.sparse(4, [0,1,2], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]))], 
                           ["documento", "variables"])

df.show()      
+---------+--------------------+
|documento|           variables|
+---------+--------------------+
|        0|(4,[0,1],[11.0,2.0])|
|        1|   [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]|
|        3|(4,[0,1,2],[2.0,2...|
+---------+--------------------+
```

The document 1 is a DenseVector and the previos solution does not work because DenseVectors has not `indices` attribute, so you have to use a more general representation of vectors to work with a DataFrame which contains both sparse and dense vectors, for example `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], 
                           x[1], 
                           np.nonzero(x[1])[0].size))\
                .toDF(["documento", "variables", "frecuencia"])
df.show() 
+---------+--------------------+----------+
|documento|           variables|frecuencia|
+---------+--------------------+----------+
|        0|(4,[0,1],[11.0,2.0])|         2|
|        1|   [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]|         4|
|        3|(4,[0,1,2],[2.0,2...|         3|
+---------+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hello Amanda.
Your answer worked plenty. It solved the issue. I was not aware about what you said: _VectorAssembler_ not always create _SparseVectors_, thanks for the info.

Comment: VectorAssembler generates SparseVectors or DenseVectors based on the number of zero features in each row. If one row has a lot of zero features then a SparseVector will be created but, in the opposite case (a lot of non-zero features), then a DenseVector is generated because is more expensive create a tuple with the non-zero indices and non-zero values. Potentially, it could duplicate the consumed memory with two vectors of the same size as the original features vector.